# D7 Unique page/profile per user

Tags: 7, users

I am working a lot with views and panels to figure this out but i cant.

When user register account i want for him to be able to make his own profile visible to everyone.
Profile is 1 page user can create with custom content type (maybe there is something better to use?) with info from taxonomy vocabulary, random text, a gallery and a calendar.
Since there is lot of info to write in i want to separate this in few steps.
So i would like to divide page in few regions that look same for all users. Gallery on left side, taxonomy terms and random text in middle, calendar on right side or in block. Each region editable by user who made it. All info on that specific page must be only from user that created it (only userA pictures, userA calendar, userA random text on. All on 1 page).

I worked a lot with panels and views but i have no idea how to make all of this in a way that all info created by 1 user is on 1 page, viewable by everyone on that page.

I managed to use views to collect info from all users in 1 field/block/page so i know some basics. Also used panel to divide for example /home in more regions to.

Cheers!

Comment: Does the solution have to specifically use Panels?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should really be pretty simple if you have created the Views properly.

You need to make the views select only the content that the user provided through an argument, fx uid = 5 would should show content user with uid 5 created.

Then it's just a matter of creating a panel page that has the uid in the url, fx `user/[uid]/profile` and pass the uid to the views when you insert them on the page, which then will display the correct content.

Comment: Not sure if i understand this correctly so ill try to elaborate.

I should make custom content that is panel, which when users makes content automaticly creates page and uses views to know what and how to display ?

Comment: @BigBrother2010: No you make a panel page which will display whatever content the user has created you want to display, gallery,calendar etc. You use views to display this content by using the uid of the user as an argument.